# mod_wsgi not working with pinax of django

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, web-deployment-project, pinax

I tried hard to configure mod_wsgi for an pinax project.  I followed the exact instructions from the site (pinaxproject.org), unfortunately, I always got the following error:

[Thu Aug 26 17:32:46 2010] [error] [client 173.48.119.55] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=26749): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'www.mysiste.com-production' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.26745.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.

here is the code:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xxx.xx:80> 
    ServerName mysite.com 
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin mymailg@yahoo.com

   WSGIDaemonProcess www.mysite.com-production python-path=/usr/pinax/pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
   WSGIProcessGroup www.mysite.com-production
   WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/pinax/newsino/deploy/pinax.wsgi
   <Directory /usr/pinax/newsino/deploy>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Alias /robots.txt /srv/www/newsino/public_html/robots.txt
   Alias /favicon.ico /srv/www/newsino/public_html/favicon.ico
   Alias /images /srv/www/newsino/public_html/images
   Alias /static /srv/www/newsino/public_html/static

   ErrorLog /srv/www/newsino/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/newsino/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets

Setup WSGISocketPrefix directive as indicated.